# switching from msmq private queue to public

Tags: .net, queue, msmq, private, public

Currently I am working or using msmq private queue, I need to change this to public queue.
What I find is, I need to change only endpoint address

```
address="net.msmq://132.186.201.193/private/IEventQueue"
```

TO

```
address="net.msmq://132.186.201.193/public/IEventQueue"
```

However, this is not working and i am facing the exception as

`There was an error opening the queue. Ensure that MSMQ is installed and running, the queue exists and has proper authorization to be read from. The inner exception may contain additional information. ---> System.ServiceModel.MsmqException: An error occurred while opening the queue:The queue does not exist or you do not have sufficient permissions to perform the operation. (-1072824317, 0xc00e0003). The  message cannot be sent or received from the queue. Ensure that MSMQ is installed and running. Also ensure that the queue is available to open with the required access mode and authorization.`

What am I missing here , in config?

Regards,
Ani

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the existing queue, you will need to create a new public queue.

Edit following comment:

Yes, you can post remotely to a private queue, but you need to get the name and address exactly right - see http://www.infosysblogs.com/microsoft/2007/02/msmq_sending_message_to_remote.html

Comment: Yes, "Public" and "Private" aren't different ways to access the same queue. Private$\queuename and "Public"\queuename are different items with their own unique properties.

Comment: hello frnds, i want to put my services on diff diff machine and want to ulitise it , for this reason i want to make my queue as public , is there any othere way or i can do same thing with private queue also ?